# Manipulate and FileNameSetter don't want to play nice together

Tags: manipulate, files-and-directories

In a `Manipulate`, one can specific the type of an individual control like so:

```
Manipulate[v, {v, Red, ColorSetter}]
```

I tried to do the same with `FileNameSetter`, i.e.

```
Manipulate[v, {v, "no file chosen", FileNameSetter}]
```

but that doesn't work, and the control is a slider. I can work around the issue like so:

```
Manipulate[{v, FileNameSetter[Dynamic[v]]}, {v, "no file chosen"}, 
  ControlType -> None]
```

but I would rather understand why my second example above doesn’t behave as expected. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Manipulate` does not directly support a [control type](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ControlType.html) called "`FileNameSetter`", but fortunately it is possible to use custom controls (both in `Manipulate` and other functions), as described e.g. in the [`Control`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Control.html) documentation:

> `{u,func}`        an arbitrary control from a function

The trick to getting it working is that `func` must be a pure function.  This is mentioned in the [Advanced Manipulate Tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedManipulateFunctionality.html), in the section showing how to build a custom slider.

So, somewhat unusually, `Control[{v, FileNameSetter}]` will not work, but `Control[{v, FileNameSetter[##]&}]` will.  The equivalent construction using `Manipulate` would be:

```
Manipulate[v, {{v, "none"}, FileNameSetter[##] &}]
```

(Of course things would be much simpler if `Manipulate` would just support `FileNameSetter` directly as it does `ColorSetter`)

Comment: Oh, you are good… So, let me get this straight: using `FileNameSetter` does not work, but `FileNameSetter[##]&` does? (as does `FileNameSetter[#]&`) How crazy!

Comment: @F'x Yes, it's quite nasty ... a function should be a function regardless of which kind it is.  It's just not nice that only a pure function works in this case ... but I can understand why: how would one detect in a reasonable way if a symbol can be considered a function or not?

Comment: It seems to me that the documentation is misleading because if you follow the `{u,func}` pattern where `u` is a variable you might think `Manipulate[v, {v, FileNameSetter[##] &}]` would work and it does, after a fashion...the variable `v` is initialized to `func` and thereafter takes the expected value.