# ListPlot dynamical problems

Tags: programming, dynamic

I have `Manipulate`, where there are

- `FileNameSetter`(to load file with data points)
- `InputField` for  setting a function
- "Plot region" to present graph of function and scatter of points .

Firstly I had hardcoded the path to file and function too.
So after Evaluate there are correctly drawn graph and scatter.
After I change the function, it dynamically changes in graph.
But nothing happen, when I push the button (FileNameSetter)
Could you tell me, please, what am I doing wrong.

```
  fil = NotebookDirectory[] <> "Example.tsv"  (*hardcode*);
data4 = Import[fil];
data4 = RandomChoice[data4, 2000];
Q4 = (data4[[All, 2]]);(*cars/s*)p4 = (data4[[All, 2]]/
   data4[[All, 3]]);(*cars/m*)Qp = 
 Transpose@{p4, Q4};(*scatter preparation*)
Manipulate
[
  (*"Plot region"*)
  Show[
   ListPlot[Qp, PlotRange -> All, 
    AxesLabel -> {"p, cars/m", "Q, cars/s"}],
   Plot[
    {f[p]}, {p, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"p, АТС/метр", ""}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}
    ],
   ImageSize -> plotWidth
   ],
  (*button*) 
  Style["boundary conditions ", Bold], FileNameSetter[Dynamic[fil]],

  (*this way,I set a function.P.S.no problem here,I guess*) 
  DynamicModule[
   {
    code = 
     Hold[f[x_] :> 
       If[x < 0.05, -6044 x^3 + 231 x^2 + 22.22222222222222 x, 
        If[x < 0.09, -3755 x^3 + 767 x^2 - 48 x + 1.913758680555557`, 
         If[x <= 0.7, 1.672 (0.7 - x), 0]]]]
    },
   With[
    {
     fn = (
        code = #;
        ReleaseHold[# /. RuleDelayed -> SetDelayed]
        ) &
     },
    Manipulate[
     Column[
      {
       Labeled[
        InputField[Dynamic[code, fn], Hold[Expression], 
         FieldSize -> 80 ], "Q(\[Rho])", Left, 
        LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold]]
       }
      ],
     Initialization :> fn[code]
     ]
    ]
   ]
  ];

 (*/this way, I set a function. P.S. no problem here, I guess*)
```

Comment: I would suggest that you try to reduce your problem to a minimal example that concentrates on the issue you are having (i.e. the file loading). It may make it more likely for people to answer your question.

Comment: The code you have posted does not work. It has several syntax errors, so It is impossible to discern what your real problem is. I will say that your whole approach looks wrong to me and shows very little understanding of the _Mathematica_ functions you are attempting to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the code you posted does not execute as-is, your report that it works on your end as far as the initialization of the input field and plot region go. I will therefore only tackle the problem with `FileNameSetter` here.

It has been reported before that Manipulate doesn't directly accept `FileNameSetter` as a control type ([Manipulate and FileNameSetter don't want to play nice together](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14345/27951)), but Szabolcs showed how it can be tweaked to accept it by using a pure function form (see [his answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14347/27951)).

In your application, that goes a long way towards solving your problem, but you will want to combine that with two further changes:

1. The plotting function will complain if you invoke it before a file has been selected, because there is no valid data set to plot. To fix that, you can either provide a default filename to load at start, or ask the user for one upon initialization. The latter solution seems preferable to me, as it is more self-contained and it won't be broken if you accidentally delete your default file. We will accomplish that using `Initialization` within `Manipulate`.
2. The initialization typically works synchronously, i.e. `Manipulate` doesn't wait for it to be done before evaluating the rest of the code. We need to fix that, so the user has time to select a file to plot before `Manipulate` proceeds. We can fix that by using `SynchronousInitialization -> False` as an option to `Manipulate`.

Taken those two points into account, here is a simplified working solution:

```
Manipulate[
  data = Import[filename, "TSV"];
  ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All],
  {filename, FileNameSetter[##] &},
  Initialization :> (filename = SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]),
  SynchronousInitialization -> False
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you very much.
I had already tried to make a minimal example of a problem, but, unfortunately, inaccurate, so it was hard to understand.
Your advices helped me. Now, after Evaluate, data loads immediately, and, after I choose other file with data, the scatter change too.
But this procedures are located in "object"(like a function in c++), i call it resultingControl. 
ResultingControl is the first procedure, the program begins with it, and it activates the other "object" resultingPlot,
which performs some calculations. In these calculations I need those loaded data files too.

Comment: But,after I have used Your advice, there is an error like "First argument fil is not a valid file, directory, or URL \
specification".
Is the problem in local, global variables?
To prevent misunderstanding( now I realy couldn't imagine, how should I make minimal example correctly) I put the code here http://pastebin.com/vcjtUyNy

Comment: resultingPlot in the middle, here would be 2 imports, which don't work.
resultingControl is located in the end.
I hope, You could  notice what's wrong without calling Evaluate, from code only, because, to make it working example of data (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85852447/data.2137-1.tsv) and one these dll is needed ( for win64 https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85852447/lab2-x86-64.dll and win32 https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85852447/lab2-x86.dll)
And this is too bold asking You to load all of this.

Comment: @MishinV. Unfortunately I won't be able to go through your code, as it is too long and complicated. I understand that it will be hard, but I can only suggest that you try to isolate the portion of the code that doesn't work, attempt to reduce it to the smallest sample that displays the same behavior, and post another question about it.

Comment: Thank you again to your attention! I've prepared the code, but could you try to go through it again to say "better" or "not"  before I publish it. http://pastebin.com/Y5LPNnzr  the code is working with datafile you could download

Comment: wait a minute , I solve it

Comment: I just put dataReal = data4; and it works . don't know why. Thank you!

Comment: @MishinV. I am really glad to hear that your code is working for you now!

Comment: last question to Your method. It's possible somehow to remove "filename" before browse?

Comment: @MishinV I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Do you want the code not to ask for a file first?

Comment: "Do you want the code not to ask for a file first?" that's ok.
I mean, is it possible to show only Browse button?[http://imgur.com/NA3VVRg](http://imgur.com/NA3VVRg)

Comment: I have surfed the site, but in Your variant of code  {filename, FileNameSetter[##] &} I couldn't find any options to answer my question.

Comment: @Mishin I see what you mean now. I'm on a table now, so I don't have MMA in front of me, but let me try a few things out when I get to my computer.

Comment: @Mishin Try this: `{{filename, Automatic, ""}, FileNameSetter[##] &}` instead of the existing manipulator variable definition.

Comment: I can't thank you enough!

Comment: @Mishin You are welcome.